# Cloudtrail logs is turned off for your account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-step-functions, amazon-cloudtrail, cloudwatch-alarms

I'm trying to trigger AWS Step Function whenever a new file is uploaded on S3 bucket. I'm using Cloudwatch rules to do this but I'm getting this warning

[image]

I tried to follow AWS documentation link "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-cloudwatch-events-s3.html#tutorial-cloudwatch-events-s3-step-1" but state machine did not invoked.
Can anyone tell me what exactly I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I created this trail and region is Ohio

[image]

Comment: Well, turn it on?

Comment: it's already turned on and it did not work.

Comment: In which region was S3 bucket created?
Is Cloudtrail monitoring that region?

Comment: @caba I have added the screenshot of the trail I created. Please have a look at edit section.

Comment: S3 bucket is in Ohio region.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, we need to enable data events as well to get API calls for S3. It was not mentioned in above AWS Document.